# Hidden Pre Typed Text in Text area Showing in All Fields After Submission

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, css

[image]I made a PHP request form and have pre-typed some text in the text-area and made it `display: none;` with its id and name attribute in the PHP form. I have other fields with input and textarea and their assigned id and name( for example `id="othertexts" name="othertexts"` I have made a hide/show text area, in which I have text area with pre-typed text with its own `id="hiddentexts" name="hiddentexts" style="display: none;"`

The problem I'm facing or having is when I user fills and submits the data in php form from `othertexts` field but when I get the email from the user I see data from `othertexts` and the from the hidden pre typed text from `id="hiddentexts" name="hiddentexts"`

im checking in my index.php
`if(isset($_SESSION["data"]["GM Groups"])) { $gm_list = $_SESSION["data"]["GM Groups"]; } else { $gm_list = "";}`

send_mail.php
`$usersGMGroup = nl2br($_POST["acc_GMGroup"]);`   and then from where the index.php is pulling the data from `hasData("GM Groups", $usersGMGroup);`

I have tried and test most of the ways I found online but nothing seems to work

```js
$(function() {
  $("#groups").change(function() {
    //GM Group
    {
      if ($(this).val() == "GM") {
        $("#groups_GM").show();
      } else {
        $("#groups_GM").hide();
        $("#acc_GMGroup").hide();
      }
    }
  });
});
$('#groups').trigger('change');
```

```css
html,
body {
  min-height: 100%;
}

body,
div,
form,
input,
label {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  outline: none;
  font-family: Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #666;
  line-height: 19px;
}

legend {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #095484;
  padding: 3px 5px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

h1 {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 36px;
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 2;
}

.testbox {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: inherit;
  padding: 20px;
}

form {
  width: 75%;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 50px 0 #095484;
}

.banner {
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  background-image: url("/New_Website/Walgreens Logo's/Walgreens New Logo/banner.png");
  background-size: cover;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.banner::after {
  content: "";
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

input {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

input {
  width: calc(100% - 10px);
  padding: 5px;
}

select {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 3px 0;
  background: transparent;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.hiddenField {
  display: none;
}

table.tb {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 650px;
}

.tb th,
.tb td {
  padding: 6px;
  border: solid 1px #262626;
}

.tb th,
.tb td {
  color: #262626;
}

.tb th {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

textarea {
  white-space: pre;
  text-align: left;
  width: 650px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-6">
  <label for="userReqEmp">Requestor Name</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control w-100" id="userReqEmp" name="userReqEmp" placeholder="Type Here...">
</div>
<div class="col-6">
  <label for="userNameEmp">Full Name</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control w-100" id="userNameEmp" name="userNameEmp" placeholder="Type Here...">
</div>
<div class="col-6">
  <label for="userComEmp">Comments (Optional)</label>
  <textarea type="text" class="form-control w-100" id="userComEmp" name="userComEmp" rows="7" placeholder="Type Here..."></textarea>
</div>
<div class="col-6">
  <div class="row">
    <label class="col-12" for="userEIDEmp">Employee ID</label>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <input type="text" class="form-control w-100" id="userEIDEmp" name="userEIDEmp" placeholder="Type Here...">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <label class="col-12" for="userOIDEmp">One ID</label>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <input type="text" class="form-control w-100" id="userOIDEmp" name="userOIDEmp" placeholder="Type Here...">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <label class="col-12" for="userDateEmp">Start Date</label>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <input type="date" class="form-control w-100" id="userDateEmp" name="userDateEmp" placeholder="Type Here...">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <label class="col-12">Select Department</label>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <select id="groups" name="groups" class="form-control w-100">
        <option value="">Select an option</option>
        <option value="GM">GM</option>
        <option value="AGM">AGM</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <!-- GM -->
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-12" id="groups_GM" name="groups_GM" style="display: none;">
      <h2>DC GM Group</h2>
      <table class="tb">
        <tr>
          <th>Domain Group Access</th>
          <!-- Title -->
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Wag-$Woodland<br>Managers</td>
          <!-- Content -->
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Distribution List</th>
          <!-- Title -->
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>WoodlandInventory<br>WoodlandSrManagers</td>
          <!-- Content -->
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Additional Access</th>
          <!-- Title -->
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>DCNet<br>AS400 (JOB-CAT-01)<br>VPN Non-Standard</td>
          <!-- Content -->
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-6">
  <!-- style="visibility:hidden;" -->
  <textarea class="textarea" style="display: none;" id="acc_GMGroup" name="acc_GMGroup" rows="5" col="2">
            <u>Domain Group Access</u>
            Wag-$Woodland
            Managers

            <u>Distribution List</u>
            WoodlandInventory
            WoodlandSrManagers

            <u>Additional Access</u>
            DCNet
            AS400 (JOB-CAT-01)
            VPN Non-Standard
        </textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: If you need your textarea contents to be ignored upon form submission in some cases, use the `disabled` attribute for that textarea.

Comment: @Jared I used disabled attribute but it still show in other name fields when wen form is filled and submit

Comment: I still don't understand what are you trying to achieve. Values of the form elements are not sent to server if they have `disabled` attribute set or they have no `name` attribute. If you want to prevent a fair user to change an input value, make that input `hidden`. It might be `disabled` aswell.

Comment: @Jared The problem is when I submit the form request from another select option for example if I select option IT Request from the form and fill its input and submit it & when I get results in HTML email I also get the hidden text area texts that were pre type for Employee select option and it also shows with the IT request details. I want the pre type text to show only to its assigned name

Comment: Assining `display:none` to your textarea will not prevent browser from sending it to the server. Replace `$("#acc_GMGroup").hide()` with `$("#acc_GMGroup").hide().prop('disabled', true)` to make it disabled so browser knows this should not be sent.

Comment: `$("#acc_GMGroup").hide().prop('disabled', true)` this didnt work. I have attached a image of what i trying to achieve from my question. All the data in the brackets and marked does not belong to that field, its belongs to the Employee field

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242830/discussion-between-krrish-and-jared).